# Amazon EC2 Mysql update

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, yum

What is the latest version of mysql in amazon EC2 and how do I update it? I currently have this version:[image]

Comment: EC2 provides virtual machines on which you run your choice of software stack.  So, you can run any version of MySQL that you like; upgrade instructions are dependent on your operating system.

Comment: thanks for your response @eggyal ....I meant the pre-installed mysql version (yum)